# App collapsed when retrieving data from wampserver

Tags: android, database

My app connected to the wampserver that the android virtual machine can show the data successfully, but it is not possible to do that on my phone.

Here is the error message shown.

03-16 16:42:02.859: D/-heap(6912): GC_CONCURRENT freed 89K, 5% free 8096K/8455K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 31ms
03-16 16:43:07.699: W/System.err(6912): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to .

Localhost refused.

Please help me to find what I did wrong. Is it the URL got something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to enter direct IP address of the server - not only localhost? Localhost IP address on emulator is 10.0.2.2. 
[See more here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to change the ip already. But it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put wampserver online.

left click the wamp tray icon and press "PUT ONLINE"

If you have the latest version of WampServer , there is a known bug that stops LAN accecs from working.

To fix the bug in WampServer you need to open httpd.conf (c:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.x.x\bin\httpd.conf)

Find these 3 lines(or very similar due to the bug)  and delete them.

```
# Online --> Require all granted

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Require local
```

Replace with these lines

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
```

You may think they are the same, but WampSever uses a search pattern to find them and white space affects it. 
Save the file and left click the wamp tray icon, click "Put Online/Offline"  3 or 4 times until the switch gets back inline with the code and then leave it online.

If you now check the httpd.conf you will see that Wamp will modify the above line depending if the switch is ONLINE or OFFLINE  " Require all granted" OR "Require local". This was not happening before due to white space between the lines

In windows, open CMD and type IPCONFIG

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connector:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

You will use the IPv4 address to connect to Wamp from other Devices on the network.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded the latest services of wampserver. And I have tried to change the ip to 10.0.2.2. That is ok for emulator, but not for the phone. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to delete the 3 lines and update them. It use the lPv4 address to connect. But I still can't use my phone's app to retrieve data from wampserver. So, can you give me more advice to do so? Thanks so much.